# how to create nuget package that uninstalls itself right after install?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

What I want to achieve is create package that works like NuGetPSVariables. After Install-Package it does it's work and uninstalls itself.

I tried to download NuGetPSVariables package using Powershell script - http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/02/02/downloading-a-local-nuget-repository-with-powershell.aspx and check it's scripts but it wasn't downloaded, weird.

I want my package to download snippets and disappear (leaving snippets). Maybe you have some other suggestions on how it should work?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Nuget Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/) to view the contents of that package and see how it does auto-uninstall.

Comment: But the problem is I don't have that package (I mentioned it wasn't downloaded). How to download it?

Comment: OK using command line 'nuget install NuGetPSVariables' I downloaded it.

Comment: That's the point: Package Explorer can download packages straight from the feed. You don't need to have them locally. nuget.exe can do that as well, but is more cumbersome if you just want to take a peek inside.